Cannot set up Vue DevTools plugin in electron Vue3 Vite app
I am trying to create an electron application using electron forge, Vue3 and Vite by following the instructions at https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/vue-3 .
I have modified the following files as requested by the tutorial:

index.html
src/App.vue
src/renderer.js

At this point I can start the electron application using npm run start without any issues, but I don't have access to Vue DevTools.
However, when I modify the last file, vite.renderer.config.mjs I run into a problem.
When I run npm run start, the application gets to the "compiling main process code" step and ... stops. There is no error message or warning.

You can absolutely use the Vue3 devtools in electron. For this, the "electron-devtools-installer" npm package is the official way to do so
Just import the required devtools and use them in the main.js file.
import installExtension, { VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'

//........
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  installExtension(VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS)
    .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
    .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err))

  electronApp.setAppUserModelId('com.electron')
  app.on('browser-window-created', (_, window) => {
    optimizer.watchWindowShortcuts(window)
  })


  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})


If you mean you cant use the browser extension, im sorry to tell you, but you cant install extensions in electron.
Also: its better to set up the app using npm create vite@latest which will guide you through the installation. First, you have to choose the name of the app. Then, you'll see an option of frameworks to choose from. Choose others and then the "electron" option. It now lets you choose between different frameworks, you can choose which ever you want, i recommend vue. Just like that, you made a new vite + vue + electron app.
